# Filebeat is not running in ubuntu machine after ELK setup

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat

I was trying to configure ELK in one of ubuntu server and filebeat in another ubuntu machine. After changing the file configuration which is /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml I am not seeing that filebeat is running.

Where I can check filebeat logs and what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

if installed filebeat from installer search for log path in /var/log/filebeat.

check for yml for any syntax error and user permission to run the filebeat.